# Проблема с textarea: в Хроме автоматически принимается padding

Tags: css, textarea

Есть код:

```
<div class="block" style="background: #ccc;">
 <textarea style="font-size: 11px; font-family: tahoma; padding: 4px;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Почему-то в chrome автоматически принимается padding, а в других же браузерах всё нормально. В чём проблема?

**Chrome**

[image]

**Остальные браузеры**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow: [How do I fix inconsistent Textarea bottom margin in Firefox and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453959/how-do-i-fix-inconsistent-textarea-bottom-margin-in-firefox-and-chrome)

```
textarea {display:block}
```

Answer (score 0):

`margin` и `padding` по нулям сделайте.

Comment: Не помогает ):

<style type="text/css">
.block {
 background: #ccc; 
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0ж
}

#wall_text {
 background: #fff; 
 border: 1px solid red; 
 padding: 10px; 
 margin: 0; 
 resize: none; 
 outline: none; 
 font-size: 12px; 
 font-family: tahoma; 
 height: 14px;
}
</style>

<div class="block"><textarea id="wall_text"></textarea></div>

Answer (score 0):

!important к padding и margin добавьте

Comment: @rimlin, не помогает...